# How to make an Alpine.js switch component bring value to form?

Tags: alpine.js

For the following simple Alpine.js switch component:

```
<div x-data="{on : true}">
    <form action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1">
        Enabled : <span x-text="on ? '[$]' : '[ ]'" @click="on = !on" name="enabled"></span><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

When `on` = true, how to make the form submit "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?enabled=on"?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a hidden input

```html
<div x-data="{on : true}">
    <form action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1">
        Enabled : <span x-text="on ? '[$]' : '[ ]'" @click="on = !on" >
    <template x-if="on">
        <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="on">
    </template>
 </span><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```